# Powershell - Test-path looking for 3 files

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to create a powershell script that will check for 3 specific files in a folder.  If the 3 files exist continue.

I keep trying to use test-path command.  The closest i got was this:

```
$checkwim = test-path $imagepath\* -include OS.wim, data.wim, backup.wim.
```

This however does't work for me as it returns "True" if any of the 3 are found.  I need to make sure all 3 exist.

I got it to work using the below but i was hoping for an easier\shorter method.

```
$checkwimos = test-path $imagepath\* -include OS.wim
$checkwimdata = test-path $imagepath\* -include Data.wim
$checkwimonline = test-path $imagepath\* -include Online.wim

if (($checkwimos -ne $True) -or ($checkwimdata -ne $True) -or ($checkwimonline -ne $True))
{
Echo "WIM file(s) not located.  Script Aborting"
exit
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another tack:

```
$files = @('os.wim','data.wim','backup.wim')

if (($files | foreach {test-path $imagepath\$_}) -contains $false)
 { 
   Echo "WIM file(s) not located.  Script Aborting"
   exit
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, i like this one the best as it allows us to easily adjust for the number of files.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to avoid hard coding a check for each file type to include you could do something like this:

```
$files = @('os.wim','data.wim','backup.wim')
$checkWim = $files | foreach-object {test-path $imagepath\* -Include $_} | Where-Object {$_ -eq $false}
If($checkWim -eq $false){"WIM file(s) not located.  Script Aborting"}
else{
#do stuff
}
```

You could also import a list of file instead of creating an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is already pretty simple, although you could make it a bit more readable with:

```
$checkwimos = test-path (Join-Path $imagepath OS.wim)
$checkwimdata = test-path (Join-Path $imagepath Data.wim)
$checkwimonline = test-path (Join-Path $imagepath Online.wim)

if (-not ($checkwimos -and $checkwimdata -and $checkwimonline))
{
Echo "WIM file(s) not located.  Script Aborting"
exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on a one-liner, the below should work.

```
if (@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\temp\" | Where-Object -FilterScript {@("os.wim", "data.wim", "backup.wim") -ccontains $_.Name}).Count -eq 3)
{
write "Files were present"
}
```